# Ionic 3 - canvas draw - how to save and load?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, canvas

I have created an app that allow users to draw and painting any thing

these are the main functions of drawing canvas

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

    this.canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;

    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.canvasElement, 'width', this.platform.width() + '');
    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.canvasElement, 'height', this.platform.height() + '');

}

handleStart(ev){
    this.lastX = ev.touches[0].pageX;
    this.lastY = ev.touches[0].pageY;
}

handleMove(ev){

    let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    let currentX = ev.touches[0].pageX;
    let currentY = ev.touches[0].pageY;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.currentColour;
    ctx.lineWidth = this.brushSize;
    ctx.stroke();

    this.lastX = currentX;
    this.lastY = currentY;

}
```

I need to add save and load functions

> Only what i need to do is store canvas value in variable to be able to load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after hours of work

for save i used this way

```
saveCanvas(){
  this.saved = this.canvasElement.toDataURL();
}
```

for load i used this way

```
loadCanvas(){
  this.clearCanvas();
  var canvas = this.canvasElement;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // load image from data url
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    };

    imageObj.src = this.saved;
    // make ajax call to get image data url
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('GET', 'https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/dataURL.txt', true);
 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
   if(request.readyState == 4) {
     // Makes sure it's found the file.
     if(request.status == 200) {
       loadCanvas(request.responseText);
     }
   }
 };
 request.send(null);

}
```